# Select From Insert Into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three datatables, `tableA`, `tableB`, and `tableAB`. The contents aren't really important, just that `tableA` and `tableB` have primary keys and `tableAB`relates the keys in the two tables. The basic structure is below:

```
aId|data
---+----
1  |4
2  |83

bId|data
---+----
1  |a
2  |cd
3  |bf

abId|aId|bId
----+---+---
1   |1  |1
2   |1  |2
3   |2  |3
```

What I'd like to do is combine the inserts of all three of these tables into one query, but am not sure how to. The current idea that I'm working with is below, but it does not work. Important things to note are `aId`'s may refer to multiple `bId`'s, but each `bId` will only have one `aId` referring to it. As such, `aId`'s may not refer to existing `bId`'s. The big things I am struggling with are 1) making the value of an `insert` come from another `insert`, and 2) simulating multiple inserts, for `bId`'s, in a single query.

Current query:

```
insert into tableAB(aId, bId) 
values((select aId from(insert into tableA(data) values(5))), 
       (select bId from(insert into tableB(data) values("f"))));
```

I'm really not sure multiple inserts in a single query is possible and don't know a way of writing it above.

Comment: Multi-table inserts in a single query are not supported by MySQL. :(

Comment: You could do what you want in Postgres, but MySQL does not support inserts into multiple tables in a single query.

Comment: There is a LAST_INSERT_ID, see the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8102/1/0

Comment: `INSERT` queries don't return a value, you can't use them as subqueries in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the IDs of the first two inserts.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (data) VALUES (5);
SET @idA = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO tableB (data) VALUES ('f');
SET @idB = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO tablAB(aId, bId) VALUES (@idA, @idB);
```

You could put this all into a stored procedure.

Comment: I had forgotten about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a single query.

But you could use a `TRANSACTION` instead:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO tableA(data) VALUES(5);
    SET @aid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO tableB(data) VALUES('f');
    SET @bid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO tableAB(aId, bId) VALUES(@aid,@bid);
COMMIT;
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the id of previously inserted row. It is then stored in a user variable using `SET` and can thereby be referenced in following statements.

Comment: Isn't this the same as @Barmar's answer, except with rollback control? It seems, specifically to my question, your answer and his are functionally the same

Comment: @yanman1234 He posted only a couple of minutes after me, so he could have been working on it at the same time.

Comment: And using a transaction for related queries like this is a good idea.

Comment: I didn't mean for it to sound like an accusation of copying or anything, I was just trying to see if there was more to his answer in using `transaction` or if fundamentally both the answers were equivalents. I've personally never used `transaction` before which is why I asked.

Comment: When you use a `TRANSACTION` you make sure that none of the changes become permanent until `COMMIT` is executed. If say your server crashes after the first `INSERT` statement you don't end up with rows in tableA with no relations to tableB where your application might expect at least one. You wanted to perform all inserts in a single query so I expected that this behaviour was what you sought.

Comment: Yes that is the expected behavior I desired, thank you for the explaination

Comment: @Kilgore, I would if your answer solved my initial question. I was looking for a way to combine multiple inserts into one query, which your answer did not provide. I did learn `transaction` from your answer, but I had already considered multiple queries of insertions, hence the question of combining them into one.